# Dynamically Change Color of Text ONLY in GridView

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I'm writing an ASP.NET app (using VB). I have conditional formatting of gridview rows based on content. I want to be able to change the color of the text as part of this. I tried using:

e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red

The problem is that this turns the borders red too. Any way to change just the text color, or force the borders back to black?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

`e.Row.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;`

after changing `ForeColor`

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If I look at HTML markup on render page it has class="RowStyle" style="border-color: black;" Anyway, I figured a way to tweak my css to force it

Answer (score 0):

ForeColor should work, try this though:

`e.Row.ForeColor = Color.FromName("#f00");`

Comment: ForeColor is working for the text. Problem is it's changing the border too

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been over a year since this question was posted, but I actually just ran into this problem as well.

Gloria was on the right track, but the problem is that the cells use the row's `ForeColor` for their borders.

This means that you need to change the border color on each cell in the row as well:

```
// After setting Row.ForeColor
foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
{
    cell.BorderColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Or with LINQ:

```
// After setting Row.ForeColor
e.Row.Cells.Cast<TableCell>.ToList().ForEach(c => c.BorderColor = Color.Black);
```